# Radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { \frac{1}{n!} \cdot x^{n!}} $

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

How do we find the radius of convergence $R$ of this power sum?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { \frac{1}{n!} \cdot x^{n!}} $$

How do we handle the $n!$ as the power of $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of $x$ as fixed. Your series is of the form $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ with $a_n={x^{n!}\over n!}$.

One has
$$
{a_{n+1}\over a_n}= {x^{(n+1)!}\over (n+1)!}\cdot {n!\over x^{n!}}
={x^{(n+1) \cdot n!}\over x^{n!}} \cdot {1\over n+1}={x^{n\cdot n!}\over n+1}.
$$
As $n$ tends to infinity, these ratios tend to zero for $|x|\le1$ and diverge to infinity  for $|x|>1$ (you should provide details here).

Consequently the radius of convergence of your series is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your $a_n$ is such that $a_{n!}=\frac{1}{n!}$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise. You'll have to use the root test, that is, what is $$\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}\text{ ? }$$

Alternatively, note that this *surely* converges for any $|x|<1$. (Why?) It also converges for $x=1,-1$. But what happens if $|x|>1$?

Comment: I like the alternative better, +1.

Comment: @julien Yes. Though it provides the ratio alright. The limsup is $=1$.

Comment: @julien Hmm. I like David's alternative better.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u_n=\frac{1}{n!}x^{n!}$ then
$$\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}|x|^{(n+1)!}\times \frac{n!}{|x|^{n!}}=\frac{|x|^{n\times n!}}{n+1}\to\ell=0<1\iff|x|\leq1$$
so
$$R=1$$